# AngularJs post to .NET Controller always null

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs

I'm trying to post data from an Angular controller to a .NET end point.

The angular function looks like this:

```
vm.save = function () {
$http({
   url: 'Home/Save',
   method: 'POST',
   data: vm.colours,
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   header: {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
  })
  .success(function (response) {
                alert(response)
            }
        )

  };
```

And the end point looks like this:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public void Save([FromBody]Colours input)
{
     var temp = input;
}
```

The data posted to the end point is:
[Post header from Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpDhh.png)

And the Colours model:

```
public class Colours
{
    public string color { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public List<Code> codes { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Code
{
    public string rgba { get; set; }
    public string hex { get; set; }
}
```

If I fire the save function I hit the end point, and I've tried changing the end point to be plain string/pass a plain string and removing the [FromBody], but the value passed in is always null.

I've also tried changing the angular to the shorthand version of the post, but I don't think this is the issue, if I check the http response that is posted the data is all present so the disconnect must be somewhere else.

There are a lot of issues revolving around the $http.post coming up with a null value, but none of the solutions have seemed to fix my problem.

What am I missing? I'm relatively new to angular, so it could be something obvious.

Comment: What's the contents of the `vm.colours` in Angular? Are you sure that the data being sent is properly formatted to be deserialized into an instance of your `Colours` class in C#?

Comment: Try this, change the signature of C# function to `public void Save(string input)` then within that code try to de-serialize to C# object using Newtonsoft Json.Net. Make sure that the string generated by serializing C# object using Newtonsoft Json.Net is same as that you are sending JSON object from angular. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Your code should work as long as `vm.colours` is an object with same structure as of `Colours` class.

Comment: 1. Go to developer window of browser 
2. Send data how u are sending now
3.check the data
4.u need to set format as like in the API input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had an epiphany and solved my problem, the issue was that the object being sent is an array of Colours rather than a single Colour. Changed the end point to be like below and this solved the issue:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public void Save(List<Colours> input)
{
    var temp = input;
}
```